# After iOS 5 update can't open Photos.app

Tags: iphone, ios, photos.app

Camera works and stores somewhere photos. But I can't open Photo.app...
I have tried many things to solve this problem:

1. Quiting Photo.app
2. iPhone restrat
3. iPhone restore

Image Capture doesn't sea any photos as well.

All the same.

Do you have any ideas how to troubleshot this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Were you in the iOS 5 Beta for registered Apple developers? I experienced a similar issue where Photos would not open, or it would sometimes open and indicate that it was loading the pictures, but it never completed the operation. This happened because I had videos as well as photos on my iCloud Photo Stream. I went to iCloud.com and deleted everything on my Photo Stream. That solved the problem. I was then able able to take pictures and video and open the Photos app as usual.

Comment: No, it was usual update. I don't sea my Photo Stream on icloud.com. Image Capture doen't recognize any photos as well.

Comment: You want to open "Photos" and not something called "Photo.app"...

Comment: Yes, I just want to view my photos (camera roll).

Comment: I assume you mean iPhoto.app?

Comment: no he means the photo app on an iDevice!!

Answer (score 1):

Symptoms of what happens when you attempt to open the iOS Photos app would be helpful in troubleshooting this issue. If it opens and then immediately closes, it's crashing. If you've tried an actual restore of the OS, the only way that app will continue to crash is if you continue to restore from the backup, which will preserve the problem. Restore the unit, decline restoring from the backup, and test further.